# Como gerar um gráfico múltiplo horizontal usando python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ciência-de-dados, seaborn

Boa tarde, estou realizando um trabalho para a faculdade onde necessito gerar um gráfico múltiplo em barras horizontais.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
df_escolaridade['Espacialidades'] = df_escolaridade['Espacialidades'].astype("string") 
df_escolaridade

index = []
for col in df_escolaridade.columns[2:]: 
  df_escolaridade[col] = pd.to_numeric(df_escolaridade[col],errors='coerce')
  index.append(col)

ax = df_escolaridade.plot.barh(figsize=(15,10), y = index)
```

e gerou este resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém gostaria que o gráfico fosse separado por cidade, exemplo do gráfico gerado no excel:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue dataframe que estou utilizando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço as respostas, muito obrigado!

Comment: Miguel, boa noite! Tudo bom? consegue disponibilizar os dados pra teste? Não precisa ser o csv/excel completo. Abraço!

Comment: Tudo bem, e ai? segue link do dataframe exportado em csv e upado no github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/migueelcruz/DataScience_Dengue/master/dataframe.csv?token=AMYYYLNFIE3PMKDAQYDHKBK7OD5E6

Comment: está dando erro 404

Comment: Peço desculpas, sou novo usando o github, segue link do csv no google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o9PsP0QO6jR4eVLg3TQsVvrY4L-QzxFJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: relaxa! agora funcionou!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Carregando o data frame:

```
df_escolaridade = pd.read_csv('./dataframe.csv', index_col=[0])
df_escolaridade.drop(columns = 'Código', inplace = True)
```

Verificando os tipos de dados:

```
df_escolaridade.dtypes
```

```
% dos ocupados com fundamental completo - 18 anos ou mais 2010    float64
% dos ocupados com médio completo - 18 anos ou mais 2010          float64
% dos ocupados com superior completo - 18 anos ou mais 2010       float64
% de 18 a 20 anos com médio completo 2010                         float64
% de 15 a 17 anos com fundamental completo 2010                   float64
% de 18 a 24 anos com fundamental completo 2010                   float64
% de 18 anos ou mais com fundamental completo 2010                float64
% de 25 anos ou mais com fundamental completo 2010                float64
% de 18 a 24 anos com médio completo 2010                         float64
% de 18 anos ou mais com médio completo 2010                      float64
% de 25 anos ou mais com médio completo 2010                      float64
% de 25 anos ou mais com superior completo 2010                   float64
Expectativa de anos de estudo 2010                                float64
```

*Aqui é onde deslocamos as colunas para as linhas, fazendo o pivot.*

'Pivotando' o data frame:

```
df_pivotado = pd.pivot_table(df_escolaridade, values = df_escolaridade.columns, 
                                columns='Espacialidades')
```

Plotando o gráfico:

```
df_pivotado.plot(kind = 'barh', figsize = (15,10))
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Agradeço muito pela ajuda e atenção. Tenha uma ótima noite.

Comment: Por nada meu camarada! abraço! Boa noite